# Consuming SOAP in Visual Studio? Correct string in SOAP Response but empty in .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, nusoap

I'm creating a .NET app that consumes a SOAP service written in PHP. Sending data to the service is working OK, but I can't receive any data, even though they are in the SOAP response.

This is my SOAP Response:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:helloResponse xmlns:ns1='urn:oxywsdl'>
         Hello James
      </ns1:helloResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But in C#, when I call

```
Services.oxywsdl ox = new Services.oxywsdl();
MessageBox.Show(ox.hello("James"));
```

It shows just an empty MessageBox. What am I doing wrong? I spent the whole day googling, thank you!

Comment: What are you using to store that SOAP envelope.. are you using XMLReader or anything of that nature.. have you been able to get the service to even display static text without creating a soap response..? need to see more code ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my day-long suffering was caused by some bug in VS2010. All I had to do was to delete the service reference and restart VS and then add the reference again... Thank you Visual Studio!